# whats going wrong for calculating probability of getting first head at odd times using the basic approach

Tags: probability

the problem is this only : [A fair coin is tossed until a head comes up for the first time. The probability of this happening on an odd number toss is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834344/961436) .

> though my approach was different . i would like to know how to solve it using just the method of getting sample space and favourable outcomes .                                                                              what i considered lets say for now that we want the turns to be limited lets say n = 4 . for this we have total H,TH,TTH,TTTH outcomes in sample space out of which odd numbered ones where a first head appears is only 2 so we get probability to be $\frac{1}{2}$ continuing in this fashion we would get half probability only for even tries .

- whats going wrong with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your method.  The first problem is that your four outcomes are not equally likely.  Although only two of the four outcomes have an odd number of tosses, the probability that there would be one toss is $ \frac{1}{2}\ $, and the probability that there would be three tosses is $\ \frac{1}{8}\ $.  Therefore the total probability of finishing on an odd number of tosses is $\ \frac{5}{8}\ $, not $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $.

The second problem is that the total probability of your four outcomes is not $\ 1\ $, but $\ \frac{15}{16}\ $, because there's an extra possible outcome, TTTT, which you haven't listed.  Thus, while the probability of your ending after an even number of tosses is indeed $\ 1-\frac{5}{8}=\frac{3}{8}\ $, this includes the case TTTT where the final toss is *not* a head. The probability of your finishing *with a head* after an even number of tosses is only $\ \frac{5}{16}\ $, the sum of the probability of the outcome TH,  namely $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $, and the probability of the outcome TTTH,  namely $\ \frac{1}{16}\ $.

Comment: thanks this is pretty informative . so is it possible that this method i posted here is fine as this one gives the first head  outcome a bigger value then later ones in terms of favorable outcomes? and so on for next ones? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4516055/961436

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is not correct in that the stopping time of the original question was just "stop if you see head". Then the event of which we wanted to know the probability was "what is the probability that the stop happened at odd time". In your new problem, the stopping time changed to "stop if you see head and stop anyway if $n \geq 4$". These two stopping times are different, that's why you get different answers, even if you want to know in both cases the probability of the same event: "what is the probability that the stop happened at odd time". In other words, the original question can be solved using a standard geometric series (because you can stop anytime from $0$ to $\infty$), whereas in your question you cannot, as you stop anyway if $n \geq 4$.

Comment: hello by 4 i mean i am checking till 4 and see if anwhere in  1,4 the head first time occurs . so after that i generalize for even N NOT JUST N= 4

Comment: I understand that, however that approach would not work because you need to start with the possibility of stopping anytime between $0$ and $\infty$. This way you get the geometric series that results in the probability of $\frac{2}{3}$. "Checking till 4" consists in formulating a different problem, that has a different answer. In other words, you need to start with the general case right away because that's the request of the original stopping time.

Comment: generlazing shoulg give the answer as we can put n infinty instead of 4 half would be favourable outcomes

Comment: Not always such approach works in mathematics; there are famous examples of things that work in some way for finite cases and for the infinite case work differently. One famous example is the proof that the cartesian product of infinitely many compact spaces is compact. In proving the fact that a cartesian product of connected spaces is connected, one proves it first for finite products and derives the general case from that. In proving that cartesian products of compact spaces are compact, there is no way to go from finite products to infinite ones. The infinite case demands a new approach.

Comment: See Tychonoff theorem for a reference.

Comment: okay fine i am posting a new question on this same topic but a bit different . i think i may get a new realization there .